# Issue in Facebook login

Tags: android

I am trying to get the email id from facebook,Using facebook SDK I tried integrating the stuff but something went terribly wrong and I am not getting the email id from the facebook.:(

I think I followed the procedure of getting the  app id and all that sort of stuff.

```
  Error ApiException:Key hash +AxK1TuWWiB/3LdT7XI3MzkaORM does
  not match any stored key hashes.
```

This is the exception I am getting, Even after a lot of googling I am not able to find the hash key stuff somebody please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a KeyHash for your debug and put it in the Facebook settings page

this is the line that creates the debug key hash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

when it prompts you for password, the password is `android`

and then you put the KeyHash in your settings in Facebook app

[image]

You should do this for every computer you are working on the app on.

Comment: password must be `android`? um... Also, keystore does not necessarily named as `debug.keystore`

Comment: @Raptor these are the default settings, if the user changed the name of his debug keystore, then he must also change it in the given link. I can't control "personal" settings ;) usually newbies don't change them